# Stability Boundaries via Routh-Hurwitz Criterion

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, stability

I'm attempting to determine the stability boundaries of a 2nd order system via Routh-Hurwitz stability criterion. That is to say, I need to compute when a polynomial, which is in terms of variables "a" and "c", is equal to zero. This polynomial is *very* large.
Where `R` is the system matrix,

```
R = GQ[7, X, Ginv];
cp = CharacteristicPolynomial[R, x];
cl = Reverse[CoefficientList[cp, x]];
h1 = cl[[1]]; h1 > 0
h2 = cl[[1]] cl[[2]] - cl[[3]];
```

Thus when `h2>0` the system is stable. I first tried

```
RegionPlot[h2 > 0, {a, 0, 20}, {c, 0, 20}, Mesh -> All, 
 FrameLabel -> {"a", "c"}, PlotPoints -> 120]
```

[image]

Attempt to numerically find boundaries failed miserably:

```
sol = Table[FindRoot[(h2 /. a -> n) == 0, {c, 0}], {n, 0, 3, 0.1}];
ListPlot[c /. sol, DataRange -> {0, 3}]
```

[image]

```
FindRoot::lstol: "The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than \!\(TraditionalForm\`MachinePrecision\) digits of working precision to meet these tolerances. \!\(\*ButtonBox[\">>\", ButtonStyle->\"Link\", ButtonFrame->None, ButtonData:>\"paclet:ref/message/FindRoot/lstol\", ButtonNote -> \"FindRoot::lstol\"]\)"
```

I also tried

```
Solve[H2 == 0, c]
NSolve[H2 == 0, c]
```

but after quite some time of waiting, neither evaluated. Is it possible for *Mathematica* to determine these boundaries? `RegionPlot` provides a nice picture, but I'd like to have numerical values in order to know the exact curves of the boundaries.

Comment: If you could provide sample `GQ`, `Ginv`, `x` and `X` that would be great. It would be nice to be able to recreate your graph or a similar one and then go from there.

Comment: @Pickett GQ[] is a Gaussian quadrature function I've written. I can include the matrix R. What is the preferred format of providing matrices? Can I upload it some way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simplicity, take as an example

```
h2 = c^2 + a^2;
```

Now, plot `h == 0` instead of the region `h > 0`.

```
plt = ContourPlot[h2 == 1, {a, -1, 1}, {c, -1, 1}, FrameLabel -> {"a", "c"}]
```

and extract from it the `Graphics` elements that make up the curve.

```
pts = Cases[plt, GraphicsComplex[z_, __] :> z, Infinity]
(* {{{0.0350877, -0.999373}, {-2.22045*10^-16, -1.}, {-0.0357143, -0.999351}, ... *)
```

These are, I believe the boundary points you were seeking with `FindRoot`.  The can be plotted with

```
ListPlot[pts, AspectRatio -> 1, AxesLabel -> {"a", "c"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Your plot is, of course, much more complicated, with several disjoint regions.  So, you will obtain multiple lists of points.  For instance,

```
pltc = ContourPlot[Cos[c] + Cos[a] == 1/2, {a, 0, 4 Pi}, {c, 0, 4 Pi}];
ptsc = Cases[pltc, GraphicsComplex[z_, __] :> z, Infinity];
ListPlot[ptsc, AspectRatio -> 1, AxesLabel -> {"a", "c"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note: In general, use

```
plt//InputForm
```

to see what information is available inside a `Graphics` object, but be prepared for a lot of output.